# gitlab-runner errors on local windows

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab-ci-runner, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to generate [my work in progress hugo website](https://gitlab.com/stanstrup-personal/stanstrup-web) locally. It works fine with gitlab CI.

I installed docker and the gitlab runner service.

Then using the guide [here](https://blog.typodrive.com/2017/03/04/gitlab-ci-execute-gitlab-ci-yml-locally-with-gitlab-runner-gitlab-ci-multi-runner/) I figured that I am supposed to do `gitlab-runner exec docker pages`.
But that results in:

```
[0;33mWARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of upcoming releases[0;m
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 10.5.0 (80b03db9)
[0;m[0KUsing Docker executor with image rocker/tidyverse:latest ...
[0;m[0KPulling docker image rocker/tidyverse:latest ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image sha256:f9a62417cb9b800a07695f86027801d8dfa34552c621738a80f5fed649c1bc80 for rocker/tidyverse:latest ...
[0;m[31;1mERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/c/builds/project-0/Users/jan/Desktop/gits/stanstrup-web:C:\Users\jan\Desktop\gits\stanstrup-web:ro'
[0;m[31;1mFATAL: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/c/builds/project-0/Users/jan/Desktop/gits/stanstrup-web:C:\Users\jan\Desktop\gits\stanstrup-web:ro'[0;m
```

I also tried registering it as other guides show but I end up with the same issue.

Others have had some issues:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1775 It was said it was fixed...
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12751 suggest that you can set `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`. I tried setting that as an environmental variable but it didn't help.
- More discussion of how to escape the path correctly: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3285
- More discussion sugestion `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` would work: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/607

**Am I supposed to set something in .gitlab-ci.yml? Should volumes be set there? In which case how/where?**

The .gitlab-ci.yml says:

```
image: rocker/tidyverse:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get -y install default-jdk pandoc r-base r-cran-rjava curl netcdf-bin libnetcdf-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev
  - R CMD javareconf
  - Rscript .gitlab-ci.R

pages:
  script:
    - R -e "blogdown::build_site()"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Did you use a `docker-compose.yml`? If yes then please post that too in your question

Comment: If I understood correctly the equivalent is the .gitlab-ci.yml. I have added that to the Q.

Comment: Gitlab runner is executing the compose/container here and the runner is not taking care of the path. I don't have windows to recommend what could be the possible steps you could try and explore. But the issue cannot be resolved using `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` because runner should have that variable. See if it can be passed inside the gitlab runner and make it work?

Comment: According to the link you provided (the *open* issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1775), this is a known bug due to the "colon" separator of paths under Windows; it seems that a bugfix has been devised (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/706) but it has not already been integrated and released...

Comment: I wonder why commands in `before_script` are not placed in a Dockerfile (to build your own image).

Comment: Did you check that the env var was available?

Comment: @Bob Lokerse  In the calling shell yes. Not inside the docker. How?

Comment: @JanStanstrup I guess so. Where it is used. (Sorry, I do not know the exact details). When setting env. vars. they are not always directly available in the same shell, if I remember correctly. Always good to check. ;-)

Comment: Still not fixed in version 10.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you hit the colon seperator bug in docker for windows which lots of tools have to work around , [gitlab has noticed it](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1775)

until the fix comes out the simplest workaround would be for you to try doing this in a linux vm on your windows box. 
[get prebuilt gitlab vm images from bitnami here.](https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab)

otherwise you could checkout and run the [gitlab-runner source branch with the fix](https://gitlab.com/cdhunt/gitlab-runner/tree/feature/docker-executor-windows), however it shows some conflicts and might have other bugs.